# Send a Map<String,double> to value of FormData in dio

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to send a register request to the API with `Dio`, but when I use this code, the location field has a problem:

```
class RegisterRemoteDataSourceImpl extends RegisterRemoteDataSource {
  final Dio dio;
  final String username, email, password, confirmPassword;
  final String fullname, biography;
  final LocationEntity location;
  final File? profilePicture;

  RegisterRemoteDataSourceImpl({
    required this.dio,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.confirmPassword,
    required this.fullname,
    required this.biography,
    required this.location,
    this.profilePicture,
  });

  @override
  Future<bool> register() async {
    final formData = FormData.fromMap(
      {
        "username": username,
        "email": email,
        "password": password,
        "confirm_password": confirmPassword,
        "fullname": fullname,
        "biography": biography,
        "location": jsonEncode(location.toJson() /* {"latitude": 1234.0, "longitude": 1234.0}) */,
        "profile_picture": profilePicture == null
            ? null
            : await MultipartFile.fromFile(profilePicture!.path),
      },
    );
    final response = await dio.post(
      kApiRegister,
      data: formData,
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      throw (response.statusMessage!);
    }
  }
}
```

The result I expect when I'm checking the API :

```json
{
  "token": "jfadslkjfadsljf5645456446",
  "user": {
    "id": 12,
    "username": "test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "date_joined": "2023-08-02T20:29:00.274657Z",
    "userprofile": {
      "fullname": "test",
      "biography": "this is test",
      "profile_picture": "/images/Users/user_12/IMG_20230708_171948.jpg",
      // this is true
      "location": {"latitude": 1234.0, "longitude": 1234.0}
      // this is true
    }
  }
}
```

Actual result in the API:

```json
{
  "token": "jfadslkjfadsljf5645456446",
  "user": {
    "id": 12,
    "username": "test",
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "date_joined": "2023-08-02T20:29:00.274657Z",
    "userprofile": {
      "fullname": "test",
      "biography": "this is test",
      "profile_picture": "/images/Users/user_12/IMG_20230708_171948.jpg",
      // this is my problem
      "location": "{\"latitude\":1234.0,\"longitude\":1234.0}"
      // this is my problem
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately `"location"` saved as `String`, Its must be saved as `Map<String,double>`

Comment: You can't use '{"latitude": ${location.latitude}, "longitude": ${location.longitude}}'?

Comment: You can use '{"latitude": ${location.latitude}, "longitude": ${location.longitude}} while sending the JSON values

Comment: Or you can make a  Model for JSON request .

Comment: I test this but got recent result: "{\"latitude\": 1234.0, \"longitude\": 1234.0}"

Answer (score 0):

If server supports `nested object` with `FormData`, you can use this form

```
final formData = FormData.fromMap(
  {
    "username": username,
    "email": email,
    "password": password,
    "confirm_password": confirmPassword,
    "fullname": fullname,
    "biography": biography,
    "location[latitude]": location.latitude,
    "location[longitude]": location.longitude,
    "profile_picture": profilePicture == null
        ? null
        : await MultipartFile.fromFile(profilePicture!.path),
  },
);
```

Comment: This method had no effect and the values were not saved in the database.

Comment: what framework does the server use?

Comment: i use `Dio` in `Flutter` and Api, wrote with `Django`

Comment: then, I think you should use library supports nested forms like [drf-nested-forms](https://pypi.org/project/drf-nested-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

To save data as Map<String, dynamic> don't encode it. `jsonEncode` returns String and therefore it is sent to the API as a String. Using Dio you can send any data that is "basic type" including Lists and Maps, no matter how many times they are nested in each other.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but this is possible as long as you don't use ‍`FormData`, when you use it, you have to fill your own fields with `MapEntry`, and the `key` and `value` in `MapEntry` must be `String`, that's why it must be `JsonEncode`. Also, we can not use `FormData`, but in this situation I want to upload a photo, so I have to use `FormData`.